# Update a google spreadsheet automatically when receive a new entry from google form

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-forms, textjoin

Let say we have a google spreadsheet with the following information.

[image: Spreadsheet]

The Name and Email address is gotten from people filling out a google form. The Pin is gotten by doing =(A2&" "&B2). Normally I could drag the first value down to fill out the empty cells, but is there a way that, when a new entry is added to the spreadsheet through the google form, the pin for that entry also get filled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in row 1:

```
={"Pin"; INDEX(A2:A&" "&B2:B)}
```

Comment: This is a minor issue but say I concatenate name and email as `A2:A&" and "&B2:B`, is there a way to not have "and" appear in rows that doesn't have an entry yet?

Comment: @rael346 sure. `={"Pin"; INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;A2:A&" and "&B2:B)}`

Comment: You miss a parenthesis near the end, before the curly bracket, but otherwise it works great, thanks